# Package Simple Java Programs with assets, etc

Tags: java, installation, assets

I am about to ship a simple/medium sized java SE application to a little company.

As I am a student and mostly working on Android stuff, I never had to deal with the problem of packaging assets and folder structures within a java application.

My main concern is packaging some assets (e.g. pictures) with it. On the other hand I wanted to setup a little file structure for logs etc.

Are you using some kind of installer for that?
Or do you package the images etc. in java-packages and reference to them relatively via .class.getRessources() stuff.. and thus also setup the directory structure in the application itself?

What do you think should be "recommended practice"?

I hope this question is not to general. Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: I think .class.getResources() is better. Then you just have to download a jar and no further steps needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the resources size, you can either place them in your project under the `resources` directory and refer to them using some `getResource` variation, or you can store them somewhere online (Amazon S3, your own hosting) and refer for example by web request.

For small resources the best practice is to put them inside the resources directory.

You should package your project as a jar, either by directly using the [jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/), or by using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) to do it for you, but in this case you'll have to setup your project as a maven project, [here's their famous 5 minutes guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

After you have your project packed as jar (or jars) you can [upload it to the maven repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html), or use other sites which allow you to upload your binaries, such as [bintray](https://bintray.com/).

Or you can just send the Jars by email or put them on your own hosting or something :)

Comment: to be exact: with "resources" directory you mean the src/ dir in an eclipse project, or generally the java package, right?

Or do you mean with resources a "java"-equivalent of the android assets/ folder ?

Comment: I mean a directory for resources, which could be anything under src. For maven projects for example, this will be a "resources" directory, under src/main/

Answer (score 0):

Try [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). 
For example, with maven you can use [android plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), which can run tests and log operations for your android apps

Using maven/gradle - its core skill for all cool java developers.

Comment: isn't maven more suited for dependency resolving? I am more concerned about shipping the actual application as a package to the customer.

Comment: You need to package it as jar? Maven do it. Also as ear, war, zip, tar.gz and apk.